# CUDA Parallel Cross Product

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

Disclaimer: I am fairly new to CUDA and parallel programming - so if you're not going to bother to answer my question, just ignore this, or at least point me to the right resources so I can find the answer myself.

Here's the particular problem I'm looking to solve using parallel programming. I have some 1D arrays that store 3D vectors in this format -> `[v0x, v0y, v0z, ... vnx, vny, vnz]`, where `n` is the vector, and `x`, `y`, `z` are the respective components.

Suppose I want to find the cross product between vectors `[v0, v1, ... vn]` in one array and their corresponding vectors `[v0, v1, ... vn]` in another array.

The calculation is pretty straightforward without parallelization:

```
result[x] = vec1[y]*vec2[z] - vec1[z]*vec2[y];

result[y] = vec1[z]*vec2[x] - vec1[x]*vec2[z];

result[z] = vec1[x]*vec2[y] - vec1[y]*vec2[x];
```

The problem I'm having is understanding how to implement CUDA parallelization for the arrays I currently have. Since each value in the result vector is a separate calculation, I can effectively run the above calculation for each vector in parallel. Since each component of the resulting cross product is a separate calculation, those too could run in parallel. How would I go about setting up the blocks and threads/ go about thinking about setting up the threads for such a problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The top 2 optimization priorities for any CUDA programmer are to use memory efficiently, and expose enough parallelism to hide latency.  We'll use those to guide our algorithmic choices.

A very simple thread strategy (the thread strategy answers the question, "what will each thread do or be responsible for?") in any *transformation* (as opposed to *reduction*) type problem is to have each thread be responsible for 1 output value.  Your problem fits the description of *transformation* - the output data set size is on the order of the input data set size(s).

I'll assume that you intended to have two equal length vectors containing your 3D vectors, and that you want to take the cross product of the first 3D vectors in each and the 2nd 3D vectors in each, and so on.

If we choose a thread strategy of 1 output point per thread (i.e. `result[x]` or `result[y]` or `result[z]`,  all together would be 3 output points), then we will need 3 threads to compute the output of each vector cross product. If we have enough vectors to multiply, then we will have enough threads to keep our machine "busy" and do a good job of hiding latency.  As a rule of thumb, your problem will start to become interesting on GPUs if the number of threads is 10000 or more, so this means we would want your 1D vectors to consist of about 3000 3D vectors or more.  Let's assume that is the case.

In order to tackle the memory efficiency objective, our first task is to load your vector data from global memory.  We will want this ideally to be *coalesced*, which roughly means adjacent threads access adjacent elements in memory.  We'll want the output stores to be coalesced also, and our thread strategy of choosing one output point/one vector component per thread will work nicely to support that.

For efficient memory usage, we'd like to ideally load each item from global memory only once.  Your algorithm naturally involves a small amount of *data reuse*.  The data reuse is evident since the computation of `result[y]` depends on `vec2[z]` and the computation of `result[x]` also depends on `vec2[z]` to pick just one example.  Therefore a typical strategy when there is data reuse is to load the data first into CUDA shared memory, and then allow the threads to perform their computations based on the data in shared memory.  As we will see, this makes it fairly easy/convenient for us to arrange for coalesced loads from global memory, since the global data load arrangement is no longer tightly coupled to the threads or the usage of the data for computation.

The last challenge is to figure out an indexing pattern so that each thread will select the proper elements from shared memory to multiply together.  If we look at your calculation pattern that you have depicted in your question, we see that the first load from `vec1` follows an offset pattern of +1(modulo 3) from the index that the result is being computed for.  So `x`->`y`, `y`->`z`, and `z` -> `x`. Likewise we see a +2(modulo 3) for the next load from `vec2`, another +2(modulo 3) pattern for the next load from `vec1` and another +1(modulo 3) pattern for the final load from `vec2`.

If we combine all these ideas, we can then write a kernel that should have generally efficient characteristics:

```
$ cat t1003.cu
#include <stdio.h>

#define TV1 1
#define TV2 2
const size_t N = 4096;    // number of 3D vectors
const int blksize = 192;  // choose as multiple of 3 and 32, and less than 1024
typedef float mytype;
//pairwise vector cross product
template <typename T>
__global__ void vcp(const T * __restrict__ vec1, const T * __restrict__ vec2, T * __restrict__ res, const size_t n){

  __shared__ T sv1[blksize];
  __shared__ T sv2[blksize];
  size_t idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  while (idx < 3*n){ // grid-stride loop
    // load shared memory using coalesced pattern to global memory
    sv1[threadIdx.x] = vec1[idx];
    sv2[threadIdx.x] = vec2[idx];
    // compute modulo/offset indexing for thread loads of shared data from vec1, vec2
    int my_mod = threadIdx.x%3;   // costly, but possibly hidden by global load latency
    int off1 = my_mod+1;
    if (off1 > 2) off1 -= 3;
    int off2 = my_mod+2;
    if (off2 > 2) off2 -= 3;
    __syncthreads();
    // each thread loads its computation elements from shared memory
    T t1 = sv1[threadIdx.x-my_mod+off1];
    T t2 = sv2[threadIdx.x-my_mod+off2];
    T t3 = sv1[threadIdx.x-my_mod+off2];
    T t4 = sv2[threadIdx.x-my_mod+off1];
    // compute result, and store using coalesced pattern, to global memory
    res[idx] = t1*t2-t3*t4;
    idx += gridDim.x*blockDim.x;}  // for grid-stride loop
}

int main(){

  mytype *h_v1, *h_v2, *d_v1, *d_v2, *h_res, *d_res;
  h_v1  = (mytype *)malloc(N*3*sizeof(mytype));
  h_v2  = (mytype *)malloc(N*3*sizeof(mytype));
  h_res = (mytype *)malloc(N*3*sizeof(mytype));
  cudaMalloc(&d_v1,  N*3*sizeof(mytype));
  cudaMalloc(&d_v2,  N*3*sizeof(mytype));
  cudaMalloc(&d_res, N*3*sizeof(mytype));
  for (int i = 0; i<N; i++){
    h_v1[3*i]    = TV1;
    h_v1[3*i+1]  = 0;
    h_v1[3*i+2]  = 0;
    h_v2[3*i]    = 0;
    h_v2[3*i+1]  = TV2;
    h_v2[3*i+2]  = 0;
    h_res[3*i]   = 0;
    h_res[3*i+1] = 0;
    h_res[3*i+2] = 0;}
  cudaMemcpy(d_v1, h_v1, N*3*sizeof(mytype), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_v2, h_v2, N*3*sizeof(mytype), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  vcp<<<(N*3+blksize-1)/blksize, blksize>>>(d_v1, d_v2, d_res, N);
  cudaMemcpy(h_res, d_res, N*3*sizeof(mytype), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  // verification
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) if ((h_res[3*i] != 0) || (h_res[3*i+1] != 0) || (h_res[3*i+2] != TV1*TV2)) { printf("mismatch at %d, was: %f, %f, %f, should be: %f, %f, %f\n", i, h_res[3*i], h_res[3*i+1], h_res[3*i+2], (float)0, (float)0, (float)(TV1*TV2)); return -1;}
  printf("%s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
  return 0;
}


$ nvcc t1003.cu -o t1003
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1003
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
no error
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Note that I've chosen to write the kernel using a [grid-stride loop](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/).  This isn't terribly important to this discussion, and not that relevant for this problem, because I've chosen a grid size equal to the problem size (4096*3).  However for much larger problem sizes, you might choose a smaller grid size than the overall problem size, for some possible small efficiency gain.

For such a simple problem as this, it's fairly easy to define "optimality".  The optimal scenario would be however long it takes to load the input data (just once) and write the output data.  If we consider a larger version of the test code above, changing `N` to 40960 (and making no other changes), then the total data read and written would be 40960*3*4*3 bytes.  If we profile that code and then compare to `bandwidthTest` as a proxy for peak achievable memory bandwidth, we observe:

```
$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="1" nvprof ./t1003
==27861== NVPROF is profiling process 27861, command: ./t1003
no error
==27861== Profiling application: ./t1003
==27861== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:   65.97%  162.22us         2  81.109us  77.733us  84.485us  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
                   30.04%  73.860us         1  73.860us  73.860us  73.860us  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
                    4.00%  9.8240us         1  9.8240us  9.8240us  9.8240us  void vcp<float>(float const *, float const *, float*, unsigned long)
      API calls:   99.10%  249.79ms         3  83.263ms  6.8890us  249.52ms  cudaMalloc
                    0.46%  1.1518ms        96  11.998us     374ns  454.09us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.25%  640.18us         3  213.39us  186.99us  229.86us  cudaMemcpy
                    0.10%  255.00us         1  255.00us  255.00us  255.00us  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    0.05%  133.16us         1  133.16us  133.16us  133.16us  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.03%  71.903us         1  71.903us  71.903us  71.903us  cudaLaunchKernel
                    0.01%  15.156us         1  15.156us  15.156us  15.156us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  7.0920us         3  2.3640us     711ns  4.6520us  cuDeviceGetCount
                    0.00%  2.7780us         2  1.3890us     612ns  2.1660us  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%  1.9670us         1  1.9670us  1.9670us  1.9670us  cudaGetLastError
                    0.00%     361ns         1     361ns     361ns     361ns  cudaGetErrorString
$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="1" /usr/local/cuda/samples/bin/x86_64/linux/release/bandwidthTest
[CUDA Bandwidth Test] - Starting...
Running on...

 Device 0: Tesla K20Xm
 Quick Mode

 Host to Device Bandwidth, 1 Device(s)
 PINNED Memory Transfers
   Transfer Size (Bytes)        Bandwidth(MB/s)
   33554432                     6375.8

 Device to Host Bandwidth, 1 Device(s)
 PINNED Memory Transfers
   Transfer Size (Bytes)        Bandwidth(MB/s)
   33554432                     6554.3

 Device to Device Bandwidth, 1 Device(s)
 PINNED Memory Transfers
   Transfer Size (Bytes)        Bandwidth(MB/s)
   33554432                     171220.3

Result = PASS

NOTE: The CUDA Samples are not meant for performance measurements. Results may vary when GPU Boost is enabled.
$
```

The kernel takes 9.8240us to execute, and in that time loads or stores a total of 40960*3*4*3 bytes of data.  Therefore the achieved memory bandwidth by the kernel is 40960*3*4*3/0.000009824 or 150 GB/s.  The proxy measurement for peak achievable on this GPU is 171 GB/s, so this kernel achieves 88% of the optimal throughput.  With more careful benchmarking to run the kernel twice in a row, the 2nd execution requires only 8.99us to execute.  This brings the achieved bandwidth in this case up to 96% of peak achievable throughput.